# Skylanders Giants 3DS portal compatibility with 2DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, skylanders

can I use a skylanders portal for Nintendo 3DS on a 2DS?

Comment: The 2DS is a 3DS minus the stereoscopic 3D and minus the [clamshell design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_%28form%29). what makes you think the Skylanders Portal for 3DS won't work on a 2DS?

Comment: The Skylanders portals use IR for communication, therefore, his concerns may be valid, however, the 2DS keeps the IR capability intact

Answer (score 2):

The Skylanders portals use IR (Infrared) for connecting to the 3DS console, since 2DS keeps the IR port intact, the portal should work with it as well.